# color to line plot/scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is some test data I am trying to plot.

```
x_vals = seq(0,6,by=.1)

df <- data.frame(lambda=rep(NA), x=rep(NA), y=rep(NA))

iter <- 1
for (lambda in seq(0,3,by=.5)){
  for (val in 1:length(x_vals)){
    x = x_vals[val]
    y = x**2 + 1 + lambda*(x**2 - 6*x + 8)
    df[iter,1] = lambda 
    df[iter,2] = x 
    df[iter,3] = y
    iter = iter + 1
  }
}
```

All I would like is a plot of separate lines for different values of lambda, differentiated by color. Right now I am struggling to get r to even plot multiple lines.

I suspect I missing a few arguments or lines:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour=lambda)) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: Using your code I get separate dotted lines which are colored / coloured by lambda. Have you restarted R and tried ?

Comment: Also, I just cut/pasted your code.

Comment: sorry - let me clarify my question... i want lines connecting the different dots by lambda

Comment: I see. I provided an answer, which is what I believe you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour=lambda)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line(aes(group=lambda))
```

**or**

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour=lambda, group=lambda)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line()
```

The output is as follows with lines drawn based on grouping by lambda.

[image]